# Python - Default do eixo x e eixo y não sai

Tags: python, gráfico

Estou tentando indicar meu eixo X e Y, e todas as funções funcionam.

Porém, o 'default' dos eixos não saem, fazendo com que fique os valores um em cima do outro.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xticklabels(x)

ax.set_title('grafico')
```

Minhas tentativas:

```
#ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1959, 2020, 5)) 
#ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-100, 40, 20))
```

[Imagem de exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPCTH.png)

Answer (score -1):

Descobri. Deixando o 'fig' e o 'ax', ele estava criando mais um plot em cima.

Abaixo está a versão final.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 5))

ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xticklabels(x)

ax.set_title('grafico')
```